# Any way to access transient cluster settings / state in an ElasticSearch plugin?

Tags: plugins, elasticsearch

I'd like to store some simple state (key-value pairs) that's shared across an ElasticSearch cluster, for a plugin. (N.B. -- the plugin is not just a vehicle/method to store the state, I want to use such state in the plugin.) I've tried doing this via the cluster update settings API,

```
Settings newSettings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
    .put(MY_SETTING, MY_VALUE).build();
client.admin().cluster().prepareUpdateSettings()
    .setTransientSettings(newSettings).execute().actionGet();
```

but, unfortunately, this won't work because `MY_SETTING` is not registered in `IndexDynamicSettingsModule`. I can't figure out how to hook into that module (possibly its `addDynamicSetting` method). **Is there a way to store custom key-values in the transient cluster settings**? (c.f. [HTTP API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-cluster-update-settings/)).

As for **alternatives**, it seems that the node state API can return custom values, but those are more things that one would compute and return with a plugin, rather that something that could be stored as state. Storing values in static variables, and distributing those throughout the cluster with broadcast actions is an option, but I'd prefer something simple if it exists.

Any solution needs to be reasonably robust to ElasticSearch version upgrades.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way dynamic settings are registered was changed in 0.90. So, there is no solution that would be compatible with both 0.20.x and 0.90.x versions at the same time. For 0.90.x version you can register dynamic settings using `addDynamicSettings` method:

```
public class MyPlugin extends AbstractPlugin {

    /* ... */

    public void onModule(IndexDynamicSettingsModule indexDynamicSettingsModule) {
        indexDynamicSettingsModule.addDynamicSettings("index.my.setting");
    }
}
```

As for alternatives, you can add your data to the state by implementing and registering your own [custom data factory](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/commit/dfa67bf07166d99b674646860ade1a397010f600). Then you can just update cluster state on master and listen to cluster state changes in your plugin on all nodes.

Comment: Do you have any examples of the custom data factory usage? I must be doing it wrong; I added a custom factory via `ClusterState.registerFactory`, but none of its methods (`readFrom` / `writeTo` / `toXContent`) seem to get called. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at IndexWarmersMetaData.

Comment: Thanks very much. However, in the end, I found it much simpler & less error-prone to just leverage the Elasticsearch Zookeeper plugin, and store the state values I needed in Zookeeper. (This has the added benefit of being able to look at them from external tools.) I might post the solution if it seems useful.